# Microsoft Graph API - Get photo

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

My company has an internal application where I need to pull/display pictures of all the employees from office 365 with out user intervention.

From what I read online I think I need to **call Microsoft graph getphoto API in daemon application** to achieve this as per this link  (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only).

Will this be a right approach? If yes please point me to any C# sample codes related to this.

Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly the type of application you will want to build. App-only (machine-to-machine) authentication should be used anytime you don't need a user present to execute functionality.

You can take a look at the [ASP.NET Core App Only sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-apponlytoken-webhooks-sample) to get a sense of how to register and set up your app to use app-only authentication. The sample goes on to use this access token to set up webhooks, but you can replace this logic with your custom code. You will want to select the scope **User.ReadBasic.All** to have access to users' profile photos.

Comment: Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Slight correction here.  The permission **User.ReadBasic.All** is a delegated permission.  You'll actually want to grant your app **User.Read.All** application permission.  See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions for more info on the supported User entity permissions.